# Injecting html content into a custom position in header/body using apache mod_substitute

Tags: html, apache, apache2, inject

I want to inject an html content using apache mod_substitute into a specific position in header or body, is that possible?

```
Substitute "s|</body>|
<script type=\"text/javascript\">
    var myVariable =\"abc\";
</script></body>|ni"
```

Comment: It should be possible. Did you try it?

Comment: DusanBajic tried only injecting to head and body. It seems need to use a regex or something